# How to work redirect function when result true?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I can't redirect to another page when process success. How I can do that in dispatch .then? I found a way without .then , I create a new variable default value as false , when start function I set true. After I controlled if true Its works{ blabla ?  : null }

```
  function save(control, e) {
if(control == true ){
dispatch(
  saveAction.save(
    control
  )
).then(e => {
    <Redirect to="/nextpage/"> //Don't work
}).catch(err => {
  console.log("Error");
});}}
```

button

```
<button type="submit" onClick={(e) => save(item.control ,e)}> Next Page </button>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but I've basically had a state value of `redirect`, and then in `render`, have a line that's like, `if (redirect) return <Redirect to="whatever" />;`  Then, in your `.then` block, you set that state value `this.setState({ redirect: true });`

Comment: Try adding `return` before the `Redirect` tag?

Comment: @Phix I tried with return but It didn't work

Comment: See my comment above.  You've got to return the `<Redirect />` conditionally in the same place you would return the rest of your JSX.  The conditional should be against a state value that gets updated in the `.then` block.

Comment: setRedirect(true); (sameAbove).then(e => {
        if(redirect){
        return(<Redirect to="/nextPage"/> )
      }
    }  It does't work @dmitrydwhite

Comment: I posted an answer that (I hope) better explains what I am talking about :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it's what I've used before for async redirect type stuff:

```js
const myAsyncComponent = () => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);

  // Here's your original code
  function save(control, e) {
    if (control == true ) {
      dispatch(
        saveAction.save(
          control
        )
      ).then(e => {
          // <Redirect to="/nextpage/"> //Don't work
          setRedirect(true); // should work:
      }).catch(err => {
        console.log("Error");
      });
    }
  }

  // ... any of your other stuff

  // Right before you return your usual component jsx, put this in before that:
  if (redirect) {
    return <Redirect to="/nextpage" />;
  }

  // This code won't be reached if `redirect` is true,
  // instead it will return the Redirect. But when `redirect` is false,
  // this will be returned:
  return (
    <button
      type="submit"
      onClick={(e) => save(item.control ,e)}
    >
      Next Page
    </button>
  );
};
```